# Unable to install phpmyadmin in phytec-regor-board

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to install phpmyadmin in phytec-regor-board using command `sudo-apt-get-install` and the response i am getting is Package **phpmyadmin** has no installation candidate. The OS i have installed in phytec-regor-board is YOCTO-LINUX. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about YOCTO-LINUX but that error message indicates that they don't package phpMyAdmin as part of their distribution. Your best option is going to be to install PHP, a web server, and MariaDB/MySQL through the package manager (or however you prefer) and install phpMyAdmin manually. The [phpMyAdmin manual has complete instructions](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install), which basically can be simplified to:

1. download from phpmyadmin.net,
2. uncompress the file to your web root or some other suitable location, and
3. create a configuration file `config.inc.php` if needed (although in many cases, the defaults are fine).